# Cardinality of the Union is less than the cardinality of the Cartesian product

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Suppose I have two collections of sets, $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{B_i\}_{i \in I}$. It is given in the problem that $$\mathrm{card}(A_i) < \mathrm{card}(B_i) \text{ for all }i \in I $$

I want to show that 
$$ \operatorname{card}\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) < \operatorname{card}\left( \prod_{i \in I} B_i \right)  $$

There are no stipulations given about the cardinalities of $A_i, B_i$ or $I$.

This question came up when I was looking through a book on Naive Set Theory, and it has proved intractable so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have to make use of the axiom of choice (otherwise you couldn't even prove that every cartesian product is non-empty.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as **König's Theorem** (there is also a lemma called the son of this one). We are going to assume the axiom of choice through this answer, otherwise one cannot prove this theorem (more on that at the bottom).

Michael Greinecker gave a concise argument for the fact there is no surjective function from the union to the product. Which under the axiom of choice is enough to conclude there is a surjection in the other direction, and an injection from the union to the product, as wanted. Here is a more explicit construction of an injection:

If any of the $A_i$ is empty let us drop it from the list, and remove the corresponding $B_i$ as well. I hope it's clear why this is not going to harm the result. We may also assume that the $A_i$'s are pairwise disjoint sets.

The fact that $|A_i|<|B_i|$ means that there is an injection $f_i\colon A_i\to B_i$. And there is no injection in the other direction, else by Cantor-Bernstein we would have equality rather than a sharp inequality. For simplicity we can also assume that $A_i\subsetneqq B_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Fix $\langle b_i\mid i\in I\rangle$ some sequence in the product. Let us define an injection now. Let $a\in A_j$, if $a\neq b_j$ then send $a$ to the sequence $\langle \overline b_i\mid i\in I\rangle$ such that $\overline b_i=b_i$ for $i\neq j$ and $a$ otherwise.

If $a=b_j$, we know that $B_i$ has at least two elements for every $i\in I$ then we can fix $\langle c_i\mid i\in I\rangle$ in the product, such that $c_i\neq b_i$ for every $i\in I$. So in the case $a=b_j$ we send $a$ to the sequence of $\langle \overline c_i\mid i\in I\rangle$ such that $\overline c_i=c_i$ for $i\neq j$, and $a$ otherwise.

It is not hard to see that this is an injective function. Therefore the union has cardinality less or equal than that of the product.

---

A word about the axiom of choice. It is consistent that without the axiom of choice there is a countable set of disjoint *pairs* that has no choice function. Namely $\{P_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ such that $\prod P_n=\varnothing$. It is easy to see that even if we take $A_n=\{0\}$ for all $n$, then $|A_n|=1<2=|P_n|$, and $$\left|\bigcup A_n\right| = |\{0\}| = 1 > 0 = |\varnothing| =\left|\prod P_n\right|$$

I will remark, however, that if we assume that $A_i$ and $B_i$ are all sets of ordinals then the lemma holds regardless to the axiom of choice.

Comment: I think the usual terminology is "König's Theorem" for this result and "König's Lemma" for the one about branches in trees.

Comment: @Andreas: It is? I remember only vaguely the distinction in Hebrew, but I'll change this. Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf There is a Hebrew word for Lemma?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: למה :-) (But it is possible and even likely that I was taught this as a lemma)

Comment: @Asaf Lemma=Lama? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3-HBpK3oCU

Comment: @Michael: Why? ;-)

Comment: @Asaf That's what came up when I googled  למה.

Comment: @Michael: Lama (which is written the same way as Lemma in Hebrew) is the word for *why*.

Comment: @Miha, yes. As I wrote in the first line of my answer. Although both were in opposition to set theory as far as I know (I know that *this* particular theorem was actually a result based on a murky wording by Bernstein that made Koenig believe that he had found a contradiction).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Colin McLarty listed 3 principles for constructive math: avoid AC, avoid EM, and explicitly show existence. In your opinion, can anything but finite set theory get off the ground constructively without the above assumptions?

Comment: @alancalvitti: Why would I want to do that? I already pointed that without the axiom of choice it is impossible to prove the theorem. Of course, if we're namedropping I should point out that Shelah once said that good axioms feel natural to use, and the axiom of choice is very natural. So Shelah once said - don't avoid choice. I prefer Shelah to whoever that was that you pointed to. Yes yes, I know that foundational research is a dead area and nobody can finish their research in their field, we had this discussion before.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I was only referring to *constructive* maths. Re foundational research, the problem is the opposite: it never dies, it goes on and on, unbounded without convergence. If it were foundational, don't you think at some point it would end so the research can move on to the rest of the building?

Comment: "Which under the axiom of choice is enough to conclude there is a surjection in the other direction, and an injection from the union to the product, as wanted. " Can you elaborate on where I could see a proof for this? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @jsmith: The axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement that between any two non empty sets, one must surject onto the other, and also that any surjection has an injective inverse.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:\bigcup_i A_i\to\prod_i B_i$ be any function. We show it can not be surjective. Let $\pi_i:\prod_i B_i\to B_i$ be the projection onto the $i^\text{th}$ factor for all $i$. Let $X_i=B_i\backslash \pi_i\big(f(A_i)\big)$. By assumption, $X_i\neq\emptyset$ for all $i$. So $\prod_i X_i\neq\emptyset$. By construction, an element of $\prod_i X_i$ is not in the range of $f$.

Remark: This is an old result from König. The proof here is taken from [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984127).

Answer (score 4):

This is called [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29). The proof I know is reasonably simple but not something I'd expect anyone to think up as an exercise. See the bottom of page 15 [here](http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Set_Theory_2012.pdf) (page 17 in the PDF).