# Prove that $cf(2^{cf(2^{\omega}}) \ge \omega_2$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $cf(2^{cf(2^{\omega}}) \ge \omega_2$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

$cf(2^{cf(2^{\omega}})> cf(2^{\omega}) > \omega$.

In my notes I also have written that if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then, $cf(2^{\kappa}) \ge \omega_1$.

I would like to see a proof of why $cf(2^{\kappa}) \ge \omega_1$. With this I think I could finish the original problem on my own.

Comment: Koenig's theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328255/how-to-show-kappacf-kappa-kappa